# What are the jquery ui themes?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

Strangely, I can't find any examples of the themes for the JQuery UI. UI Lightness, UI Darkness, Smoothness, Start, Redmond, Sunny, Overcast, Le Frog, etc. are options displayed in the dropdown menu on http://jqueryui.com/download/. I'd like to know if there's a place on the web that defines what these themes are. It would help me choose the most suitable theme for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the theme roller http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and select "Gallery", then click any theme you are interested to see how it look.

Comment: Wow! I never thought of clicking on the Themeroller because I didn't want to customize. The different plugins on the right also change color if you click on the different themes!